# Can WordPress email the admin about PHP errors, while hiding them from the site?

Tags: php, errors

Is it possible to have WordPress email the site administrator whenever a PHP error message is displayed? Ideally the message would also be filtered out of the HTML output, so as to avoid information disclosure.

I ask because, while `@ini_set('display_errors', 0);` is at the top of my `wp-config.php` and working nicely, I want to receive notifications about errors.

I will happily write a custom plugin to do this, if someone who knows more about WP can point me in the direction of where I might hook in to get the job done.

Final bit: Am I crazy for wanting something this out-of-the-ordinary?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Displaying PHP errors isn't really a WordPress thing, it is more of a PHP thing directly. No, I don't think you are crazy for wanting this, I had a similar need for a separate application and I wrote [this blog post](http://www.johnciacia.com/2010/12/27/php-error-handling/) which should be helpful.

Essentially, define your own error handler.

Comment: It looks like that would email me about every little mistake in every plugin I use. I tried a custom error handler in wp-config and it printed screens-full of minor notices. However, what I really want is a different question, so I'll pick an answer here and ask a new question.

Answer (score 1):

Typically, as v0idless mentioned, this is done on the server side, There any many tools to manage error logs and emails out there. The error log reporting on the server end is much more detailed than you could write in a plugin.

Though I have never tested it I believe `error_log` php function supports email.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php

Reporting constant errors can kill your site/server depending on the error threshold you have set,  I recommend you just email the error.log file once every few hours/days.

For instance on the server end:

- All fatal or hard errors are in a
  separate log file which is emailed
  immediately.( Also instant
  message/cell phone support).
- All other errors in are in another
  log file emailed every 24 hours (
  which I never read:) )
- They log files are also backed up
  every day.

I actually use rubygems to do this stuff since it's so damn easy.